# Horror Mansion Asset unity

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

I am making a horror game for Unity and am looking for a premade horror mansion, or big creepy house asset. I don't have much experience with designing 3d models so was hoping there was some asset I could use with interiors too, but I can't find much on the asset store.

Any ideas for a good asset or should I try and make my own?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, 3d models are not associated with any platform until they got imported. If Unity asset store doesn't contain any asset you like, you can search on some other sites and import them yourself, there are plenty of websites if you search. [Clara](https://clara.io/library), [archive3d](http://archive3d.net/), [cgtrader](https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models) are some of the most famous, but you can find a lot more by searching "3d house model download" on google.

Comment: Thanks I found a few good houses but none have interiors, is it impossible to get models with interiors in as well?

Comment: A fully structured and textured house is a huge work, I'm afraid you'll have to hire an artist for that.

Comment: So how would someone go about this normally? Would I create a new level when they enter the house and make an interior?

Comment: You can either have a huge 3D model containing both the outside (mansion outside+ environment) and the inside (mansion inside + props) and the player will be able to enter the mansion seamlessly. Or you can separate outside and inside in two different scenes and make a transition (when the player opens the door, you fade screen to black and fade it back when inside scene is loaded). About your search for 3D models, keep in mind that modeling is a very long process, most of what you will find on the web will be either expensive and or often not optimized for a game engine (too many polygons).